# Package declaration in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest, android-studio-3.0

I changed my packet structure to this:
[image]

How do I need to declare package in AndroidManifest.xml so it finds the R class?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="..."
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
```

Comment: not a downvoter, use refactoring option to rename package , there are other places where it is being used, let the studio do the heavy lifting

Comment: I did, it didn't affect AnrdoidManifest.xml though.

Comment: manifest needs the root package,  the sub-packages are doesn't matter here

Comment: So, package = "Application" ?

Comment: seems like you don't have a root package, it should be under `java` containing other packages like io, logic etc, maybe that's why there is no package after refactoring

Comment: It's in src/main. Just don't know what to write in the Manifest, everything I tried gives me a bad package name error.